# Creating and publishing an NPM module with ES6 collection types

Tags: typescript, npm, ecmascript-6, decorator

***Note:*** this is my first module that I would like to publish myself for others to use, as I feel it is very useful. It is a typed data-serialization engine for TypeScript. I'm a bit lost on how things should be done here, and I need a definitive answer. So thank you for jumping in today, and let's get to it...

---

I created a `npm` module that uses ES6 collection types, `Set` and `Map`. These collection types are:

- Used to fuel the internal implementation of my module
- Implicitly supported through my TypeScript/ES7 decorator-based API (as class properties)

**The internal use** of these types are not of much trouble, as, to the best of my understanding, I can simply depend on them through `package.json`, and import them in my source; and then I'm all set, they will always be there.

**On the other hand**, if I do so, it is my understanding that these imports will overwrite the *native* Map/Set objects (if available), and conflict with type-detection that I rely on *(or do these imports yield the native objects when available?)*.

---

About the above mentioned type-detection... it's best demonstrated through an **example** -- if a user were to use a `Map` object with my module, this is how it would be done:

```
// Consumer code.
class MapContainer {
    @JsonMember
    mapValues: Map<number, string>;
}
```

And this is how a Map is detected and processed *inside* my module:

```
// Internal module code.
// Just for the sake of clarity: 'sourceValue === new MapContainer().mapValues'
if (sourceValue.constructor === Map) {
    // Handle 'sourceValue' as a map object...
}
```

Now it is clearly obvious how this would cause conflicts. And this is also an issue the other way around: if a user were to `import` Map/Set as module instead of using the native available implementation, the internal code of my module would not recognize that.

**How should I define my dependencies in this case?**

- Simply jam some short polyfills into my code and let the user handle it in whatever way they can?
- Use `require('es6-map/implement')`? (how do I ensure users of my module do the same, besides mentioning it in the documentation/limitations?)
- Import `Map` and `Set` through some aliasing in my source, such as `__Map` and `__Set`, and use a string-based "class name" detection instead of comparing constructor references? (this seems dirty)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, by definition, a polyfill which applies itself unconditionally is not really a polyfill, but a hack (e.g. zone.js). A well behaved polyfill will use feature detection and only add a global if one is not already present.

You essentially have three options:

1. You can use polyfills that export their functionality instead of augmenting the global. This technique is called ponyfilling. It is a bit arbitrary as it doesn't really accomplish what polyfilling does - it does not provide a native experience. However, the advantage of this is that you can correctly depend on your implementation of choice and your users can rely on a different implementation and the two will not interfere. 
   This approach would look like

   ```
   import Map from 'es6-map'; // pony pure
   ```
2. As you noted, you have the option of not committing to a specific polyfill and instead simply documenting that your library requires that ES2015 compliant `Set` and `Map` functions exist. Your user can then choose from a variety of polyfills. The advantage of this is that, if the user wants to use a different polyfill, they can do so without increasing the size of their code which is significant for projects that target browsers. This option also allows your own code to take advantage of native implementations where available which you cannot do with option 1.
3. Another approach is to simply polyfill it yourself. This is the simplest option, in terms of how your own code is structured but is also the most likely to cause conflicts with consumers and their dependencies. Like option 2, this has the advantage of using native implementations where available. There are, however, drawbacks. You will be forcing users to pay the cost of having this functionality available whether or not they want it. Users may not be aware that your library is what is causing the polyfilled `Map` to be available in their code and may come to depend on it implicitely. Load order of your library relative to other dependencies could cause very strange and difficult to detect bugs. This approach would look like

   ```
   import 'es6-map/implement'; // mutate the global
   ```

So how does the relate to your specific use case? Most of this applies to any library that relies on features that may require polyfilling, but the specifically relevant parts are, as you suggest, related to aliasing.
There is no need to resort to string comparisons.

Instead if you are importing `Map` instead of polyfilling it (option 1. the ponyfill approach), you cannot compare the `Map` you import in your implementation to the value captured from your dependent's code because it will be a different reference and the result will generally be `false` and will certainly never be reliable. Furthermore, if you want it to work in environments with built in `Map` support, polyfilled or native, then the `Map` identifier in `sourceValue.constructor === Map` needs to refer to the global `Map` in that environment, whatever that is.

I recommend options 1 because it provides maximum compatibility and allows you to specify your dependencies properly. 
This means importing `Map` wherever you use it, as in

```
import Map from 'es6-map';
```

which will create a local. If you need to use it in a module where you are also interacting with the global `Map` then you will need to import it under an alias, as you have already considered.

It is worth noting that

```
sourceValue.constructor === Map
```

will throw in some environments if there is no `Map` on the global so you will want to check for that with something like

```
typeof Map !== 'undefined' && sourceValue.constructor === Map
```

to be safe.

Unrelatedly, please place the opening `{` on the same line as whatever requires it. This matters in JavaScript.